# Todo app with manual progress entry

Tags: todo

I am looking for a to-do app that lets me to enter task-level progress entry manually. So far many of apps do not let me do this, they just calculate the progress automatically from the list of subtasks which is not what I am looking for.

I am looking for something that supports desktop (Windows and Mac) and mobile. It can be web-based, a client is not necessary as long as I can access it from different platforms. Sync feature is a must but it does not have be server-managed, as long as I can get it to sync with other means like dropbox.

I am willing to pay or subscribe.

Comment: Why Trello doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @59507 Because Trello does not let me control the progress values directly. I can emulate what I want by attaching a 10-item checklist on the task and check one to increase the progress by 10%, but this is cumbersome because I would have to manually attach the 10-item checklist whenever I create a new task.

Comment: If your subtasks are stored elsewhere you can have a bot syncing from an external source and therefore automatically populating checklists and getting the desired progresses metering. What does not make sense is to write about progress percentages without being based on any underlying data. How else one colleague would explain another why progress is at 60%?